# why nothing displaying in reactjs webapp

Tags: reactjs

I am building a webapp with reactjs, its my first project , I have fixed all the issue but still text and background images not displaying on front end only footer displaying .

https://prnt.sc/pn7j88 Here is a screenshot
https://prnt.sc/pn7kdb its footer screenshot

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import About from './components/about';
import Blog from './components/blog';
import Contact from './components/contact';
import Footer from './components/footer';
import Menus from './components/menus';
import Projects from './components/projects';
import Reasearch from './components/reasearch';
import Services from './components/services';
import Testimonials from './components/testimonials';
import Welcome from './components/welcome'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
  <div id="colorlib-page">
    <div id="container-wrap">
    <Menus></Menus>
    <Welcome></Welcome>
    <Welcome></Welcome>
    <Services></Services>
    <Reasearch></Reasearch>     
    <Projects></Projects>
    <About></About>
    <Testimonials></Testimonials>
    <Blog></Blog>
    <Contact></Contact>
    <Footer></Footer>
    </div>
  </div>
  );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Did you check if something is returned with other components? You can just use <Menus /> to render the component.

Comment: can u pls share the App.js file

Comment: @Shivaraj yes its rendering everything but not displaying

Comment: Going to need more info. Are you getting any errors, warnings?

Comment: @RonakKhangaonkar the code in my question is the app.js code

Comment: @MiroslavGlamuzina no error in console https://prnt.sc/pn7pkc

Comment: I have used this template https://colorlib.com/preview/#digilab

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code posted above, other than the components are not returning anything here. May be you wan to post one of the other components like Menus

Comment: @Shivaraj only footer and menus components are displaying

Comment: Post Welcome component may be or send the link of the code where could be tried

Comment: @Shivaraj you can check here http://e4b4e1bb.ngrok.io/

Comment: sorry my bad I mean to say the file where you have exported the App.js @arvindpundir

Comment: @RonakKhangaonkar, I have resolved the issue, it was css issue, which was making visibility hidden